# Kendo Grid Inline editing date range validation

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I need help in my kendo grid. During inline editing add or edit I'm using 4 `kendoDatepicker`. I want to do a date range validation, for example if I select date for `Booking Date From/Until` from `-> 01/07/2020` until `-> 30/07/2020`, then when I select `Promo Valid From/Until` I need to make sure that promo valid date range must not exceed the booking date range from/until. Any idea how can I achieve this? And this validation also apply during *Add New Record* and *Edit*

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/AzIqiLib)

```
#Correct
       Booking Date From <----------------------------------------------> Booking Date Until
                   Promo Valid From <---------------------------> Promo Valid Until


#False
       Booking Date From <--------------------------------> Booking Date Until
    Promo Valid From <---------------------------> Promo Valid Until

       Booking Date From <--------------------------------> Booking Date Until
                  Promo Valid From <---------------------------> Promo Valid Until
```

Comment: witch version of kendo are you using? jQuery? mvc.net? Do you need server side and client side validation when you mention "And this validation also apply during Add New Record and Edit"

Comment: Im using JQuery version. For validation only for Client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these parameters on your Booking date pickers:

```
min: (new Date(2020, 6, 1)),
max: (new Date(2020, 6, 30)),
change: function() {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
       let datePicker = $('#promoValidFrom').data('kendoDatePicker');
        
        datePicker.max(this.value());
        
        if (datePicker.value() > this.value()) {
          datePicker.value(this.value());
        }
    });
}
```

Parameters `min` and `max` will set the Booking range from 2020-07-01 through 2020-07-30. Parameter `change` will make sure every change reflects on related PromoValid fields. The change event sets the `max` date of the PromoValid field and also checks if the current PromoValid date became greater than the related Booking date, it is set to the same Booking date.

Don't forget to use `.data('kendoDatePicker').trigger('change');` right after the widget initialization. It run the `change` event the first time before user starts interaction with those fields.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.617/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  
   <div id="grid"></div>
  
<script>
  var dataSource = [{
    'name'                      : 'Special 50% Discount',
    'bookingDateFrom' : '2020-07-01',
    'bookingDateUntil': '2020-07-30',
    'promoValidFrom' : '2020-07-01',
    'promoValidUntil': '2020-07-29'
  },{
    'name'                      : '10% Member',
    'bookingDateFrom' : '2020-06-01',
    'bookingDateUntil': '2020-06-20',
    'promoValidFrom' : '2020-06-02',
    'promoValidUntil': '2020-06-10'
  }];
      
  var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    editable: "inline",
    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add" }],
    columns: [
      { field: "name", title: "Promo Name" },
      
      { field: "bookingDateFrom", title: "Booking Date From", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", 
         editor: BookingDateFrom},
      
      
      { field: "bookingDateUntil", title: "Booking Date Until", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
         editor: BookingDateUntil},
  
      
      { field: "promoValidFrom", title: "Promo Valid From", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
        editor: PromoValidFrom},
      
      
      { field: "promoValidUntil", title: "Promo Valid Until", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
        editor: PromoValidUntil},
      
      { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: " " }
    ]
  });
  
  
  function BookingDateFrom(container, options){
    $('<input type="text" name="' + options.field + '"  id="' + options.field + '" />')
    .appendTo(container)
      .kendoDatePicker({
        min: new Date(),
        month: {
            empty: '<div class="k-state-disabled">#= data.value #</div>'
        },
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
        min: (new Date(2020, 6, 1)),
        max: (new Date(2020, 6, 30)),
        change: function() {
          window.setTimeout(() => {
            let datePicker = $('#promoValidFrom').data('kendoDatePicker');
            
            datePicker.max(this.value());
            
            if (datePicker.value() > this.value()) {
              datePicker.value(this.value());
            }
          });
        }
        }).data('kendoDatePicker').trigger('change');
        $('<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="bookingDateFrom"></span>').appendTo(container);
  }  
  

  function BookingDateUntil(container, options){
    $('<input type="text" name="' + options.field + '"  id="' + options.field + '" />')
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoDatePicker({
        month: {
            empty: '<div class="k-state-disabled">#= data.value #</div>'
        },
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy",
        min: (new Date(2020, 6, 1)),
        max: (new Date(2020, 6, 30)),
        change: function() {
          window.setTimeout(() => {
            let datePicker = $('#promoValidUntil').data('kendoDatePicker');
            
            datePicker.max(this.value());
            
            if (datePicker.value() > this.value()) {
              datePicker.value(this.value());
            }
          });
        }
        }).data('kendoDatePicker').trigger('change');
        $('<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="bookingDateUntil"></span>').appendTo(container);
  }  
 
  
  
  function PromoValidFrom(container, options){
    $('<input type="text" name="' + options.field + '"  id="' + options.field + '" />')
    .appendTo(container)
      .kendoDatePicker({
        month: {
            empty: '<div class="k-state-disabled">#= data.value #</div>'
        },
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy"
        });
        $('<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="promoValidFrom"></span>').appendTo(container);
  }  
  

  function PromoValidUntil(container, options){
    $('<input type="text" name="' + options.field + '"  id="' + options.field + '" />')
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoDatePicker({
        month: {
            empty: '<div class="k-state-disabled">#= data.value #</div>'
        },
        format: "MM/dd/yyyy"
        });
        $('<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="promoValidUntil"></span>').appendTo(container);
  }  
  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AzIqiLib/2)